# Room flowable cache

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-room

I am using Room (1.0.0.rc1) with RX, my Dao is defined is this way:

```
@Dao
interface AccountDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Account ORDER BY name")
    fun all(): Flowable<List<Account>>
}
```

I am subscribing this way:

```
dao
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { accounts = it }
```

I have more than one place in the code who subscribes to the flowable. The first to subscribe gets the data, the other ones don't.

How can I make an observable that will emit the actual content every time someones subscribes and will also notify every subscriber when the data changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replay` to emit lastest value every time someone subscribes. And use `distinctUntilChanged` to notify only when data changes.

Here is the sample:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject;

public class Q47000608 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> bs = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(1);
    Observable<Integer> o = bs.replay(1).autoConnect().distinctUntilChanged();
    o.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("s1 accept " + i));
    bs.onNext(2);
    o.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("s2 accept " + i));
    o.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("s3 accept " + i));
    bs.onNext(3);
    o.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("s4 accept " + i));
    bs.onNext(4);
  }
}
```

And output:

```
s1 accept 1
s1 accept 2
s2 accept 2
s3 accept 2
s1 accept 3
s2 accept 3
s3 accept 3
s4 accept 3
s1 accept 4
s2 accept 4
s3 accept 4
s4 accept 4
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I discovered that the problem was not with my flowable, but with your answer I was able to discover it, so thanks again :)